# How conditionally update a column that contains delimited values with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, key, duplicates

I am trying to update multiple records (about a thousand of them) using this single statement (this is a process that will run every night).  The statement below only includes 3 products for simplicity:

```
INSERT INTO productinventory
  (ProductID, VendorID, CustomerPrice, ProductOverrides)
VALUES
  (123, 3, 100.00, 'CustomerPrice'),
  (124, 3, 100.00, 'CustomerPrice'),
  (125, 3, 100.00, 'CustomerPrice')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  CustomerPrice = VALUES(CustomerPrice),
  ProductOverrides = CONCAT_WS(',', ProductOverrides, 'CustomerPrice')
;
```

Everything works fine except that the `ProductOverrides` column gets the text `'CustomerPrice'` added to it every time this statement runs, so it ends up looking like this after it runs twice:

```
CustomerPrice,CustomerPrice
```

What I want the statement to do is to add `'CustomerPrice'` to the `ProductOverrides` column, but *only if* that string does not already exist there.  So that no matter how many times I run this statement, it only includes that string once.  How do I modify this statement to achieve that?

Comment: See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Comment: I don't think this will solve my problem without creating a whole lot more problems.  The ProductOverrides column tells the system not update a column when the main data feed runs.  It looks for a column name in that field and ignores it if it exists.  There has got to be a way to check if a string exists in a column, then ignore it in MYSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
INSERT INTO productinventory (ProductID, VendorID, CustomerPrice, ProductOverrides) 
VALUES 
(123, 3, 100.00, 'CustomerPrice'), 
(124, 3, 100.00, 'CustomerPrice'), 
(125, 3, 100.00, 'CustomerPrice') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  CustomerPrice = VALUES(CustomerPrice), 
  ProductOverrides = IF(FIND_IN_SET(VALUES(ProductOverrides), ProductOverrides) > 0, 
                        ProductOverrides, 
                        CONCAT_WS(',', ProductOverrides, VALUES(ProductOverrides)));
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca8fb/1)** demo

Comment: The ProductOverrides column will contain a list of other column names that the system is to ignore during other update processes.  So a typical value in the ProductOverrides column may look like this before the above SQL statement runs: "Title,Description".  Then after it runs, I want it to look like: "Title,Description,CustomerPrice".  Would that be possible using the IF() you have above?

Comment: I understand that and my example does exactly that. I've updated sql fiddle example. Take a closer look at it. If you already have in a list a `ProductOverrides` value that you pass in your insert it won't add it again.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I ran it and it worked perfectly. Thank you!